# loan prepayment

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm modeling loan prepayment using survival analysis (in R).  Should I use calendar dates, where the loans appear and then some mature, etc., or should I use the time past the inception of a loan, where all loans are lined up at time 0?  My covariates (e.g., credit rating) are time-varying.

In other words, should I use absolute time (dates) or relative time (time since the loan inception)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loan prepayment modeling is a subject of many books. There's no way to cover it here. Period.

I'll answer your concrete questions though. The loan age is a factor as well as the vintage. The loan age is time passed since origination. The vintage is a calendar date of a loan origination.

In prepayment there's a term called "seasoning", which means that seasoned loans have higher prepayment than fresh loans. If you just got a loan, why would you prepay? The loan closing costs are non-negligible, so it takes awhile before it makes a sense to go through trouble of prepaying.

The loans originated at the same time tend to have similar characteristics, that's why the vintage is important too. It's so important that sometimes we create separate models for vintages, or at least have the dummies. For instance, mortgage loans originated in 2006 are very different from those originated in 2009. In 2006 there was so much fraud that some models have even variables representing it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I am going to give the proportional-hazard model a try.  I can model seasoning by using a time-varying parameter.  Looks like I will use the loan age as the time in the model; the vintage of the loan can be handled in a categorical variable.

Comment: I alluded to the nonlinear nature of age variable, so take that into an account. For instance, look at the PSA curve for mortgages: seasoned and fresh loans react differently to age. That depends on the product, it may not be the case for your loans, so exploratory analysis is in order.

Comment: If I have time to read one book on loan prepayment, which one do you recommend?

Comment: [Appendix A](http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/documents/huddoc?id=AR2015MMIFwdRpt.pdf) describes a complete model here, it's mortgages

Comment: If I use the Cox PH model, where the hazard function is $h(t, X) = h_0(t) \exp( \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i X_i)$, the seasoning effect should be captured by $h_0(t)$.  We are more interested in the coefficients $\beta_i$, i.e., finding out if, say, the interest rate affects the prepayment probability.

Comment: Interest rate is considered to be the primary driver of prepays, usually. There are things that will make Cox model struggle, e.g. burn out. The burnout is the phenomenon where the loan pool stops reacting to anything.

Comment: How should I handle the situation where the loan lasts until maturity (i.e., it's not prepaid)?  Do I use right-censorship?

Comment: Why would you want to sensor a loan which matured?

Comment: there are three possible outcomes -- i) the loan was prepaid before the study ends, ii) the loan matured before the study ends, and iii) the loan remains outstanding when the study ends.  Normally we handle iii) right-censorship.  Currently I am doing the same for ii) but am wondering if it's appropriate.

Comment: I don't see why you would censor the matured loan. That's the loan whose life you observed in full. Also, there are other states of loans, e.g. a loan can go delinquent (miss ayments), then default (involuntary prepayment), and the loan also can partially prepay the outstanding balance in USA if it's a residential loan.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would set a time variable in a time_to_event analysis; so time past inception of loan sounds about right. If you only include dates, there is no reference point..

Comment: No, I was asking whether I should use absolute time (dates) or relative time (time since the loan inception).